# Dynamically close the table row if row text Goes to next page in pdf using xsl fo style sheet

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a requirement that , "the content which i have to display in a table comes dynamically, if it's goes to next page i have to close the table row and open new row in next page of PDF.

I am using XSL style sheet and FOP_0_95.

**sample code which i have used to display table in PDF.**

```
                  <fo:table border="0.0px solid black" width="100%">
                    <fo:table-column column-width="100%" />
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell border="0.0px solid black" padding-before="0.5cm">
                                <fo:block font-family="Times Roman" text-align="left" font-size="9pt">
                                -- content goes here -- Row1
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell border="0.0px solid black" text-align="left" padding-before="0.2cm">
                                <fo:block font-family="Times Roman" text-align="left" font-size="9pt">
                                    -- content goes here -- Row2
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
```

for suppose , if row1 content goes to next page , then i have to close the row and open new row in next page.

Please provide me the solution in XSL.

Thanks in Advance.
Venkat.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check , is it helpful to provide me the solution.

Comment: What do you mean with _"close the row and open new row"_?

Comment: To expand on the comment by @lfurini ... is it that you wish to draw a border? Or is it that you are thinking you want to close a row and create a new one? If you only want borders drawn, then look up border-before-precedence and border-after-precedence

Comment: Yes. I want to draw the border at end of page, when content extents to next page. I will try with your solution. Thanks for response.

Comment: border-before-precedence and border-after-precedence , these attributes doesn't solve my problem. Still i am searching for solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely what you want ...

```
<fo:table width="50%"  border="1px solid black" border-before-width.conditionality="retain" border-after-width.conditionality="retain">
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border="1px solid black">
                        <fo:block font-family="Times Roman" text-align="left" font-size="9pt">
                            Tation luptatum nobis vero illum lorem sed sadipscing ipsum ipsum feugait sea dolor ipsum ut sea. Justo possim at et ipsum dolor et eum ullamcorper aliquyam rebum dolor ea labore hendrerit tempor vero nostrud. Et lorem est magna eos et et eos est. Quod eos erat nonummy sed vero praesent justo sadipscing nulla stet enim tincidunt vero at et qui aliquam. Et accusam consetetur consetetur consetetur kasd wisi ipsum no dolores tempor aliquyam commodo. Ad clita takimata molestie stet stet iriure at duo magna. Labore duis eros aliquyam. Nulla sed dolores lorem eirmod. Ex erat invidunt dolores amet no sadipscing volutpat sanctus vero eirmod et clita clita duo luptatum ut invidunt.
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
  ...
```

Drawing a border on the table and retaining border-before and border-after will draw the border at the page break when the cell splits across pages, like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: this is what exactly what i want. Thank you so much @Kevin